# How to split a txt file into multiple files excluding lines with certain content

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, startswith

I have a large .txt file that I want to split into multiple, smaller .txt files, so I'm left with readable paragraphs in each smaller .txt file.

However what I want to do is exclude certain parts of the source file from being written to a smaller file. (ie if line doesn't start with `<p>` then don't write to file).

Here is the code I have - which works fine, except it generates some files I don't want:

```
import mmap
import re

filenumber = 0

out_file = None

with open('main.txt') as x:
    for line in x:
        if line.strip() == '<p>':
             filenumber += 1
            out_file = open('narrative%03d.txt' % filenumber, 'w')
        elif line.strip().startswith('</p>') and out_file:
            out_file.close()
            out_file = None
        elif out_file:
            out_file.write(line)
if out_file:
    out_file.close()
```

What I would like to do is figure out a way of saying - run the code, but if a line starts doesn't start with `<p>` then do do nothing, and continue with the rest of the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if I haven't provided enough info!

As the source file contains html tags the easiest way for me to show you the source file is to provide a link to it:

https://archive.org/stream/warandpeace030164mbp/warandpeace030164mbp_djvu.txt

View source to see the bits I don't want including.

I just want the paragraphs from the book-

ie

His daughter, Princess He*lene, passed be- 
tween the chairs, lightly holding up the folds 
of her dress, and the smile shone still more 
radiantly on her beautiful face. Pierre gazed 
at her with rapturous, almost frightened, eyes 
as she passed him.

"Very lovely," said Prince Andrew.

I don't want the beginning of the doc which includes all the html and chapter listings etc.

Comment: It would help if you edited the question to include an example from `main.txt`

Comment: Agred - I will do this now

Comment: Hi Martin, I have done the best I with providing the txt. I figured this was the easiest way to show you what I'm working with.

Comment: This is an HTML file, as such you would do better to use a tool such as BeautifulSoup to extract all the text. You could then decide which sections you want.

Comment: I know, I have no experience (yet) with BeautifulSoup, and I was hoping there was a quicker fix/mod to my script so far to simply say - if the line != <p> then don't write out to a file. Would you maintain that I should investigate BeautifulSoup? Is there not a quicker way of parsing the file (which I have downloaded as a txt file?

Comment: `html` format does not guarantee that all your lines start with some tag, `<p>` or `<h1>`, or even that some tag will not appear _in the middle of a line_. An html parser will, however, take care of this ;-)

Comment: Hi Joël, I understand this of course - however if you look at the main content of the document, in the main body of the story, there are no embedded tags within the <p> blocks: They all look like this:

    <p>
All her invitations without exception, written in French, and delivered by a scarlet-liveried footman that morning, ran as follows:
</p>

    <p>"If you have nothing better to do, Count (or Prince), and if the prospect of spending an evening with a poor invalid is not too terrible, I shall be very charmed to see you tonight between 7 and 10&mdash;Annette Scherer."

 </p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the link you have provided, the whole of the text is contained within a single huge `<pre>...</pre>` block. As such you could easily extract it using `BeautifulSoup`.

First grab the html using something like [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), extract the text containing the single `pre` using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), then split the text up based on double newlines and remove any empty entries:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get('https://archive.org/stream/warandpeace030164mbp/warandpeace030164mbp_djvu.txt')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
war_and_peace = soup.pre.get_text()

paragraphs = war_and_peace.split('\n\n')
paragraphs[:] = [p for p in paragraphs if len(p)]       # Remove empty entries

print paragraphs[671]
```

The result would be a list of paragraphs. The script would display the following:

```
His daughter, Princess He*lene, passed be- 
tween the chairs, lightly holding up the folds 
of her dress, and the smile shone still more 
radiantly on her beautiful face. Pierre gazed 
at her with rapturous, almost frightened, eyes 
as she passed him.
```

Comment: Martin, I went away and familiarised myself with BeautifulSoup on your earlier suggestion.

Thank you so much for your help- works perfectly :) Now I need finish the app and make it insert each chunk of text into a separate txt file, or into a MySQL db. I will get to work- it will be a fun challenge!

Thank so much again.